# Viability of Magnetically started engines

Tags: jet-engine, engine, engine-starting

I am working on a school project of mine which involved testing the viability of a magnetically started jet engine. By magnetically started, I mean that there are magnets which accelerate the main shaft to speed to start the engine. The point of this is to remove the need for an APU, saving space and cost on airliners and military jets.

To provide intake air to the engine to allow it to start up without an APU, there would be a system on the bottom of the engine with small electric fans to push air to the wet section of the engine to start combustion. During the flight the electric fans would be turned off and the intake section would be used like a RAM air intake for the wet section of the engine. The magnets would be powered by the battery in the aircraft, and the small electric fans would be powered by a separate battery in the engine itself.

With all that in mind, would this be viable in a commercial or private environment? Or does the APU do its job too well to replace it?

Comment: Even an electrical start system will take a lot of power, probably more suited to an APU than onboard batteries. And I'm having a hard time understanding how these electric fans and ram air intake work with a turbofan engine.

Comment: The APU does more than just start the engines...

Comment: Magnets start pushing the blades around, while fans in another section of the engine push air via a pipe to the compressor section.   When I said RAM air intake, I mean that when inflight, the electric fans would be turned off, and the air flowing through that section would go into the compressor section. The design (so far) has it so that there is a soft 90 degree angle where the air comes in and is angled into the wet section of the engine. I probably misused the term RAM air intake, but that is the general idea.

Comment: I know that the APU has functions other than starting the engines, and that is why this is looking at the **viability** of this. In the end it could turn out to not be effective, or the mag-start could just take some functions away from the APU, but in my eyes it's an interesting idea and I want to see where it goes.

Comment: Is the use of a electrically powered electromagnetic starter generator considered?  What is the compression ratio and flow for the electric fans, and what would the power draw be for that work?

Comment: I've voted to put this question on hold because I'm not sure what your specific question actually is.

Comment: The Boeing 787 starts its engines using an electric motor (which contains magnets), but it still uses an APU to power that electric motor.

Comment: Would these "starting magnets" just be an electric motor? If not, what makes them different from an electric motor?

Comment: I thought I understood what you were asking when you were talking about the magnetics, but the "system on the bottom of the engine with small electric fans to push air to the wet section of the engine to start combustion" is not clear.  I wonder if perhaps you have some misconception about how the APU starts an engine in current designs.  Suggest to read this answer: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/33597/how-is-bleed-air-used-to-start-a-jet-engine?rq=1 and then edit your question to clarify that section.  Also I agree with all of points made by @Koyovis

Comment: Agreed daniel, i will reword that one for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three things come to mind:

- Magnets are heavy.
- Not all [compressor and turbine blades](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/25647/21091) are ferro-magnetic.
- The starter would only start the engine, and then be dead weight.

Usually, new designs are implemented when they have clear advantages over previous solutions, but I cannot see what problem this would solve. The APU is a very versatile and lightweight piece of equipment that can power up all of the systems of an airplane. Not really anyone's prime target for replacement, I reckon that [captain Sully](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/39480) would agree.